# using unordered_set custom hash and find

Tags: stl, find, c++17, hashset, unordered-set

I have a hash function for my unordered_set and I want to use find functionality of set but I'm getting error. How can I use the find functionality of set using the custom hash function?

I wanted to store a pair in the unordered set and for that I have a simple hash function and just tried to use the find functionality and it throws me error. Below is the error:

solution.cpp: In member function anagramMappings
Line 22: Char 33: error: no matching function for call to 'std::unordered_set, Solution::SimpleHash>::find(__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits, int>::value_type&)'
             it = mySet.find(A[i]);
                                 ^

```
struct SimpleHash {
    size_t operator()(const std::pair<int, int>& p) const {
    return hash<int>()(p.first) ^ hash<int>()(p.second);
    }
};

vector<int> anagramMappings(vector<int>& A, vector<int>& B) {

    vector<int> res;
    unordered_set<pair<int,int>, SimpleHash> mySet;
    unordered_set<pair<int,int>, SimpleHash>::iterator it;

    for(int i=0; i < B.size(); i++) {
        mySet.insert(make_pair(B[i],i));
    }

    for(int i=0; i<A.size(); i++) {

        it = mySet.find(A[i]);
        if(it != mySet.end()) {
            res.push_back(it->second);
        }
    }

    // for(it = mySet.begin(); it != mySet.end(); it++) {
    //     cout << it->first << " " << it->second << endl;
    // }

    return res;
}
```

When mySet.find(key) is used, it should return first element of pair

Answer (score 0):

`unordered_set<T>::find()` wants `T` as an argument - in this case, a `pair<int, int>`. You are passing a single `int`.

You might want to consider `std::unordered_map` instead, as it seems you want to treat one `int` as a lookup key and another as a value associated with that key.